# jQuery datapicker execute function when date has been selected

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-datepicker

Is it possible to execute a custom function when a date is selected from the jQuery datepicker?

I have tried using the onClose option, but that just seems to execute the function when the page loads for the first time, after that I can change the date as many times as I want and the function does not execute.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try running your code in `onSelect` function:

```
$('.datepicker').datepicker({
    dateFormat: 'dd-mm-yy',
    numberOfMonths: 1,
    onSelect: function(selected,evnt) {
         // Run your code here
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$("#id").datepicker({
    onSelect: function( date ){ 
        // do stuff
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({
    onSelect: function(dateText, obj){
         alert(dateText); // Or do something else you need it to do
    }        
});​
```

I've saved an example in a jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/GZE7D/

Answer (score 0):

Use the "onSelect" option.
Typing to hit 30 chars.